# Firebase Admin in Cloud Functions data manipulation problem

Tags: node.js, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

**Firebase Realtime Database structure**

[image: Database organizations]

`freepacks` contains 2 important elements:

1. `current`, that is the quizpack **ID** that I will download from the mobile app (retrieving it from `quizpacks`).
2. `history`, that is a node where I add all the quizpacks ID that I put in `current` over time with a scheduled function in Cloud Functions.

**What I need to do EVERY TIME THE CLOUD FUNCTION EXECUTES**

**Step 1:** Add value of `current` in `history` with the current timestamp.

**Step 2:** Substitute the `current` value with another quizpack ID that **is not** in history.

**Done**

**How I tried to accomplish this target**

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();

exports.scheduledFunction = functions.pubsub.schedule('* * * * *').onRun((context) => {

    // Current timestamp
    const dt = new Date();
    const timestamp = `${
        (dt.getMonth()+1).toString().padStart(2, '0')}/${
        dt.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0')}/${
        dt.getFullYear().toString().padStart(4, '0')} ${
        dt.getHours().toString().padStart(2, '0')}:${
        dt.getMinutes().toString().padStart(2, '0')}:${
        dt.getSeconds().toString().padStart(2, '0')}`

    // Download the entire node 'freepacks'
    return admin.database().ref('quiz/freepacks').once('value').then((currentSnap) => {
        const currentPack = currentSnap.val().current;

        // Add current to history
        admin.database().ref('quiz/freepacks/history/' + currentPack).set(timestamp);
        
        // Download entire history node
        admin.database().ref('quiz/freepacks/history').once('value').then((historySnap) => {
            const history = historySnap.val();
            console.log('HISTORY: ' + history);

            // Download entire quizpacks node
            admin.database().ref('quiz/quizpacks').once('value').then((quizpacksSnap) => {
                for(quizpack in Object.keys(quizpacksSnap.val())) {
                    console.log('ITERANDO: ' + quizpack);
                    // Add the new current if it isn't in history
                    if (historySnap[quizpack] == undefined) {
                        admin.database().ref('quiz/freepacks/current').set(quizpack);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            });

        })

    });
    
});
```

**What I get from the previous code**

Starting point:

[image: Starting point]

First execution: history updates well but updating `current` didn't work

[image: First execution]

Second execution ad so on...
`current` doesn't update anymore (it is stuck on 0)

My experience with JavaScript and Firebase Admin is ~0... What is the problem with my code? Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: What should be the next `current` pack?  `for(quizpack in Object.keys(quizpacksSnap.val())) {}` this for loop is confusing.

Comment: @Dharmaraj I used this for loop to iterate all keys in quizpacks and find the first occurrence that is not contained in history and put in current

Comment: There are issues with promise handling I'm looking into it but can you share your db as JSON? You can export it by clicking vertical ellipsis icon at top right. It'll be easier for me to test the code.

Comment: @Dharmaraj yes. I removed the `metadata` node that is not part of the problem and the `history` node inside `freepacks`, that should be automatically createted: https://creativadev.altervista.org/db_export.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing is all read/write operations return promises hence you should handle them. In this answer I used `async-await` syntax. `.ref("quiz/freepacks")` fetches the complete node i.e. current and the history so you don't have to query the history node again as in original code. Other changes are just Javascript tweaks such as using `.find()` instead of `for-loop` and so on..

Try changing your function to:

```js
exports.scheduledFunction = functions.pubsub
  .schedule("* * * * *")
  .onRun(async (context) => {
    // Getting Date
    const dt = new Date();
    const timestamp = `${(dt.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, "0")}/${dt
      .getDate()
      .toString()
      .padStart(2, "0")}/${dt.getFullYear().toString().padStart(4, "0")} ${dt
      .getHours()
      .toString()
      .padStart(2, "0")}:${dt.getMinutes().toString().padStart(2, "0")}:${dt
      .getSeconds()
      .toString()
      .padStart(2, "0")}`;

    // Download the entire node 'freepacks'
    const currentSnap = await firebase
      .database()
      .ref("quiz/freepacks")
      .once("value");

    // Checking current free pack ID and array of previous free packs
    const currentPack = currentSnap.val().current || "default";
    const freeHistoryIDs = [
      ...Object.keys(currentSnap.val().history || {}),
      currentPack,
    ];

    // Add current free pack to free history
    await firebase
      .database()
      .ref("quiz/freepacks/history/" + currentPack)
      .set(timestamp);

    // Download entire quizpacks node
    const quizpacksSnap = await firebase
      .database()
      .ref("quiz/quizpacks")
      .once("value");

    const quizPackIDs = Object.keys(quizpacksSnap.val() || {});

    const newPack = quizPackIDs.find((id) => !freeHistoryIDs.includes(id));
    console.log(newPack);
    if (!newPack) {
      console.log("No new pack found")
    }
    return firebase.database().ref("quiz/freepacks/current").set(newPack || "none");
  });
```

Comment: ERROR: TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Function.keys (<anonymous>)
at /workspace/index.js:31:17

Comment: @GabrieleFeudo Looks like we used Object.keys(undefined) on undefined... please try updated which will default to `{}` if history is empty

Comment: I figured out the problem. The node `history` was not in the database in the first execution, but i moved the code under "// Add current free pack to free history" BEFORE the "// Checking current free pack ID and array of previous free packs" and now is working PERFECTLY.
You saved me ❤️